# dyld: Library not loaded despite correct rpath

Tags: c++, macos, linker, shared-libraries, rpath

I am debugging a problem where I am trying to link against a `dylib`, and set the program's rpath to a directory containing the library.

I have narrowed this to the following MWE:

```
> ls deps/include/spinnaker/
AVIRecorder.h    Camera.h      CameraPtr.h    Exception.h …bunch of headers
> ls deps/lib/libSpinnaker.dylib*
deps/lib/libSpinnaker.dylib  deps/lib/libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60
> cat test.cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <Event.h>          // for CameraList
#include <CameraList.h>          // for CameraList
#include <CameraPtr.h>           // for CameraPtr
#include <ImagePtr.h>            // for ImagePtr
#include <SystemPtr.h>           // for SystemPtr

int main()
{
  const auto system_ptr = Spinnaker::System::GetInstance();

}
```

I compile this with

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -o wat -I deps/include/spinnaker/ -L deps/lib/ -lSpinnaker -Wl,-rpath,./deps/lib test.cpp
```

And thus `libSpinnaker` gets referenced as shown by

```
[…]
Load command 9
     cmd LC_UUID
 cmdsize 24
    uuid B4498482-D872-3270-AC47-102914DDBCBE
Load command 10
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 32
 platform 1
    minos 10.15
      sdk 10.15.6
   ntools 1
     tool 3
  version 609.8
Load command 11
      cmd LC_SOURCE_VERSION
  cmdsize 16
  version 0.0
Load command 12
       cmd LC_MAIN
   cmdsize 24
  entryoff 16224
 stacksize 0
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60 (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
Load command 14
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 902.1.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 15
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 1281.100.1
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 16
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 24
         path ./deps/lib (offset 12)
Load command 17
      cmd LC_FUNCTION_STARTS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 49312
 datasize 8
Load command 18
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 49320
 datasize 0
```

So the `LC_RPATH` is included, the library is present at the specified path, but still I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60
  Referenced from: <binary-path>
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

when running it.

Now my observation is that `@rpath` is missing before the reference to `libSpinnaker` in the `otool` output – for other libraries its always there when I look at my larger cmake-based project. I would expect the line

```
         name @rpath/libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60 (offset 24)
```

instead of what i am seeing.
I can set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and that'll work, but I want to bake this into the binary with the rpath  mechanism.

**Question:** Is the fact that `@rpath` is missing here indicative of a problem? And if so, how can I get it added with the compiler or CMake? If this is not the problem, what is it?

Comment: Can you show the `install_name_tool` command you used?

Comment: I am not using any, what would that be for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
install_name_tool -id @rpath/libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60 deps/lib/libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60 

install_name_tool -change libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60 @rpath/libSpinnaker.dylib.1.24.0.60 wat
```

You noticed that the `@rpath` was missing from the installed name of the library. `install_name_tool` is the command which allows you to change the installed pathnames, add or remove @rpaths, etc. Because of the modifications, `install_name_tool` should be used before `codesign`.  [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/embedding-nonstandard-code-structures-in-a-bundle) has an example of how to setup this type of relative structure.

Comment: Is the problem that the vendor library is doing something wrong, or that my build process does not apply this modification?

Comment: No, this step is a necessary one, the libraries and your executive objects will be born agnostic as to their relative locations, although they are compiled and linked to work together already.

Comment: What I mean is why this is necessary for this library, but when I link against other libs which I have compiled from source, this is not necessary? This problematic library here is from a vendor, so my question is basically if their build process "causes" this problem or why it occurs only in this case but not generally with any library I use and have installed in a non-standard location.

Comment: The "problem" is that the two files need to be married, but come supplied as not having been married. If you are supplied a library with an insufficient InstallName for your particular purposes, there is no reason to blame the process upstream that is providing the library. Use the command to specify how you want to use the library, as other developers dependent on that build may have other requirements as to relative path setting.

Comment: Ok, I'm just confused why this issue pops up for me now and never with any of the dozens of libs i might be installing from source, that also no nothing about my application.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that you are specifying the correct `@rpath` for your project when you generate from source.  You give up that control when relying on a 3rd party build.